# Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the 'andWhere' part of this query?

Tags: plugin-development, query

What am I doing wrong in the 'andWhere' part of this query? I've tried a variety of different ways of doing it but nothing seems to work... It just seems to be ignored. Does anyone know the proper way I should be doing it?

```
foreach($entryIds as $entryId) {
    $data[] = craft()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('amforms_content')       
    ->where(array(
            'elementId' => $entryId
    ))
    ->andWhere('dateCreated > 2017-02-11')
    ->queryAll();
}

return array($data);
```

Comment: Try: `->andWhere('dateCreated > "2017-02-11"')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for comparing a date should be:

```
->andWhere('dateCreated > "2017-02-11"')
```